# Process Output Capture is VERY slow

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm currently running the following code in order to test if an external application is actually consuming one of my dll's (updater code)

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
 {
      FileName = "Tasklist.exe",
      Arguments = @"/m MyServices.dll",
      CreateNoWindow = true,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      UseShellExecute = false
 };
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo = psi;
 p.Start();
 //debug output box, just to see everything that returns
 txtOutput.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
 Refresh();

 if (txtOutput.Text.Contains("TestProgram.exe"))
      MessageBox.Show("Found It");
```

Now, this code WORKS!!!....but its STUPID slow.  I can type that same command into a cmd window and get a response in a tenth of a second, but for some reason the pause on that line `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` is taking anywhere from 1 to 5 MINUTES!!

And now the actual question:

Does anyone know why it would be that slow? Or possibly how to fix it and make it acceptably fast?

**Update: More data**

If I use a shell window and dont actually Capture the output, I can watch the task run in the shell window.  It runs marginally (very marginally) faster, but still sits and takes a minute before the output starts appearing in the shell window.  No idea what its doing.

Comment: Hrm, I've never seen this problem before. Your sample appears to be using it just fine.

Comment: Alternatively....if anyone knows of another way to test if a specific (named) program is using a specific (named) dll, let me know.  No 3rd party programs can be shipped with the client app, so something like Handle is not an option.

Comment: Maybe your handling of output data blocks the child process until a timeout occurs. You need to pull from stderr, too.

Comment: It blocks, just for not quite as long, if I dont handle the output at all and just let it run in a shell window...which is useless for my purposes anyway but a good thing to know.

Comment: If it also blocks in a shell window, then what is the problem? Also, what did you mean with: "I get a response in a tenth of a second". Does it block or does it not block? Please clarify.

Comment: if I run it using JUST a command window, not from my code, just using windows command line, and typing in `tasklist.exe /m MyServices.dll` the output shows almost immeditately.  If I change my code to use a shell window instead of running silently and capturing the output, it STILL blocks for a minute or so before showing output.  Also, the output does not all appear at once but visibly comes through line by line. one line or so a second after the blocking stops.

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader.ReadToEnd` will block until all the data is read. Try using the [`Process.OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;
p.Start();

p.BeginOutputReadLine();

p.WaitForExit();
p.OutputDataReceived -= OutputHandler;

private void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    txtOutput.Text += outLine.Data;
}
```

Comment: That was actually the second test that I ran (not shown here).  While its true, that the process doesn't block, it doesn't speed up the returned output either.  It still takes 2 or 3 minutes to get the entire output block.

Comment: That seems abnormal. When was the last time you restarted the computer?

Comment: Crazy Windows, Always with the "Did you reboot the computer".  Good question though, its been a while now that I think on it...I usually just hibernate every weekday for about month then install updates and reboot...should probably get out of that habit at some point...had an older computer that got me INTO this habit because it took 5 minutes to boot....(gone now, thankfully)

Comment: No change after full system reboot btw.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is really old, but I've just run into the same issue and just found a fix: use the x64 tasklist on x64 computers. Using the x86 .exe like you are here (in SysWow64) will result in a really long execution time - it doesn't hang, it just processes it really slowly. You should be using this file:

```
C:\Windows\sysnative\tasklist.exe
```